# Чи правильно вживати слово „боязнь“?

Tags: синоніми

Завжди думала, що це русизм або застаріле слово і правильний відповідник — слово *страх*, але нещодавно побачила *боязнь* в книзі. Чи є синонімами ці слова і чи взагалі можна вживати слово *боязнь*? На [Wiktionary](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C#%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0) сумнівне визначення:

> почуття страху; побоювання, неспо­кій, викликані ким-, чим-небудь. *Серце його занило-зав'яло: страх не страх, якась боязнь обняла його* (Панас Мирний)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На жаль, у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/bojaznj) вже є це слово:

> БОЯ́ЗНЬ, і, жін. Почуття страху; побоювання, неспокій, викликані ким-,
>   чим-небудь. Серце його занило-зав'яло: страх не страх, якась боязнь
>   обняла його (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 61);

Але у словнику Грінченка цього слова [немає](http://hrinchenko.com/takogo-slova-net.html#show_point):

> У словнику української мови Б. Грінченка не вдалося знайти потрібне
>   слово. Під час введення слова у поле пошуку звертайте увагу на
>   пропоновані слова з випадаючого списку.

У [Кримського і Єфремова з компанією](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on) перекладають як страх, острах:

> Боя́знь – о́страх перед чим і до чого, страх, бо́ясть (р. -сти), бій
>   (р. бо́ю), бо́яння. [З о́страху до вла́ди. Нія́кого бо́ю не ма́є. Я
>   нічо́го не бою́ся, і в не́ї бо́яння нема́].
>
> • Из боя́зни – з о́страху, ра́ди стра́ху.

З чим погоджуються В. Підмогильний і Є. Плужник (пересвідчитися [тут](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=3&highlight=on)).

Обережний висновок: слово таке є, в СУМі його вже пишуть як усталене, але зловживати ним не варто, бо є більш питомі українські слова, на що вказують словники поважних українських мовознавців початку ХХ сторіччя.